# ng-tags-input, storing tags data as a string array

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I'm using ng-tags input, and the data I get after populating a line is an array of object, each with one 'text' string field like so

`[{"text":"egon"},{"text":"peter"},{"text":"raymond"},{"text":"winston"}]`

Is there a way to store the data as an array of strings instead? like

```
["egon", "peter", "raymond", "winston"]
```

Comment: Nope, but I got past that by creating an empty array, then I iterated over the tags array and populated the empty array with the string values of the text fields.

Comment: Yep that will have to do.

Comment: You can use underscorejs. _.pluck(tags,'text')

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ngTagsInput only works with arrays of objects. You can easily extract an array of strings out of an array of objects, though:

```
$scope.tagsString = $scope.tags.map(function(tag) { return tag.text; });
```

**Update**

It took some time, but ngTagsInput offers now [basic support for array of strings](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/blog/2017/04/15/basic-support-for-arrays-of-strings). Starting in v3.2.0, the following is possible:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" use-strings="true"></tags-input>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s8LQTGOVdajRGBS7DPii?p=preview)

Better late than never, I guess.

Comment: tying your directive to a specific model structure (albeit you provide the `options.displayProperty` ) doesn't seem right.  This then encumbers the developer to either set up this mapping logic anywhere they might be saving a resource OR it would require some sort of setup using the `ng-model-options` getterSetter solution... again not very fun :(

If I were to provide a patch for this, would you be open to the idea?

Comment: @jusopi ngTagsInput used to work with arrays of strings only (back in v0.1 I guess). And then people said pretty much what you're saying now. Then in v1.0 I changed the code to work with arrays of objects, which is a more generic structure. And then again people say they want arrays of strings. You see, it's hard to please everyone. :) That being said, I'm always open to ideas that improve the project. If you're willing to send a PR, please do so. I'll happily review it. You might want to submit an issue on GitHub first so we can discuss how this could be implemented.

Comment: I completely understand where you're coming from.  Can't please everyone.  I will submit a proposal on github per your suggestion as I have a few questions.  Thanks for your prompt reply @Michael

Comment: @MichaelBenford What about using the `displayProperty` and/or `keyProperty` as way to customize the behavior?

Comment: +1 for having the feature that allows a developer to use array of objects or a simple array for the ng-model in such a way that if keyProperty is not provided the behaviour falls back to a simple array.

Comment: I never submitted a PR or anything as I got busy and forgot about it.  Now 2 years later I'm reading his response and my comments hahaha